# Как увеличить и уменьшить значение переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как при выполнении данного скрипта добавлять/уменьшать переменную?

```js
$(".wrapper").swipe({
    swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount){
            plus = 30;
            if(direction == "up"){
                plus_up = plus + 30;
            }
            if(direction == "down"){
                plus_up = plus - 30;
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ну если ты хочешь с помощью **инкремента** увеличить переменную на 30 то заведи цикл на 30 итераций и добавь в тело `++var`

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при выполнении скрипта переменная увеличивалась на 30 столько раз сколько выполнятся функция. У меня она выполняется единожды.

Comment: Тогда изучи https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators . Но, как уже написали - у тебя там всегда будет или 60 или 0. Когда этот блок кода начнет выполняться - переменной присвоится значение 30, независимо от того, что в ней было раньше

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
$(".wrapper").swipe({
    swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount){
            plus = 30;
            if(direction == "up"){
                plus += 30;
            }
            if(direction == "down"){
                plus -= 30;
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Это же всегда будет одно и то же значение `0` или `60`.